# how to make footer right hand side and left hand side as curve using css

Tags: html, css, formatting, footer

I have a table which has two rows and three columns. The first row serves the purpose of body and the second row serves the purpose of footer.

I want to design the footer using CSS, so that the look and feel is better. I can add the image, but there is gap between between each image so it has not come out well.

The row `tr` has three columns, and each `td` has one image.

Below is the HTML code.

```
<tr>
    <td class="FooterLeftBG"> //left css class
    </td>
    <td style="width: 85%;" class="FooterBG"> //middle css class
        <table style="width: 85%">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                some text
                </td>
                <td style="padding-top: 1px">
                some text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td  class="FooterRightBG"></td>//right css class
</tr>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
td.FooterLeftBG // CSS class for left td, used to make left hand side curve footer 
    {
    background: url('footer-leftbg.png') bottom left;
    height:35px;
    width:12px;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
    }
td.FooterRightBG // CSS class for right td, used to make right hand side curve footer
    {
    background: url('footer-right-bg.png') bottom right;
    height:35px;
    padding:0px;
    width:12px;
    float:left;
    }
td.FooterBG // CSS class for td holding the footer contents
    {
    background:url('footer-middle-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    height:35px;
    width:5px;
    }
```

Please help. I have been trying for 1 week :( I have tried through Google also.

Expected format:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7ULg.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J4zW.png

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your table inside a Div, and apply the below CSS class to it. The sample has all four curved borders, you can modify the radius values as per your requirement:

```
.container {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #909090;
    cursor: default;
    display: none;
    left: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise putting "Site optimized for Internet Explorer 9" at the bottom of your website.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with a table for your layout, you could try applying the following CSS to the `<table>` tag:

```
 border-collapse: collapse;
```

That might get rid of the space between the footer images.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cellspacing='0' to your table tag in the HTML